# EU directives during the transition period in May's Brexit deal

Tags: united-kingdom, european-union, law, brexit

May's Brexit deal includes a transition period which may last for years. The [Irish Times](https://www.irishtimes.com/news/world/europe/brexit-explained-what-is-the-transition-period-and-why-is-it-so-important-1.3671622) wrote the following on that:

> During the transition period a kind of standstill would be in place where current trading arrangements between the EU and UK would  continue. The idea is to give time for a new deal on the future relationship between the EU and UK to be worked out after the UK leaves. During the transition period the UK agrees to continue to abide by the EU’s rules and to be subject to the rulings of EU courts, but will have no say around the EU table.

This article says *"the UK agrees to continue to abide by the EU’s rules"*, but it's unclear how that works when it comes to new rules like EU directives which have to be implemented in the member states' laws.

During the transition period, would the UK have to implement (new) EU directives into UK law?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per Article 95, paragraph 1 of the [UK withdrawal agreement](https://ec.europa.eu/commission/sites/beta-political/files/draft_withdrawal_agreement_0.pdf) (page 159):

> Decisions adopted by institutions, bodies, offices and agencies of the Union before the end of the transition period, or adopted in the procedures referred to in Articles 92 and 93 after the end of the transition period, and addressed to the United Kingdom or to natural and legal persons residing or established in the United Kingdom, shall be binding on and in the United Kingdom.

In layman terms, it means: Yes, EU Directives would continue to be transcribed, and any new EU Regulation would apply to boot.